# Sales vs Service Cloud and System Administrators

Tags: licenses

We have 10 Sales Cloud licenses only 5 people have access to this and they are Salesforce System Administrators.  We have many more Service Cloud Licenses used by Staff.

My question is why were the Sales Cloud Licenses bought when no staff use Sales Cloud, shouldn't the system admin's be migrated to Service Cloud licenses (I know the cost differences etc but I am just wondering if there is a reason to keep the redundant sales cloud licenses...)

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a question for your Salesforce account executive.

Comment: Just want to make sure we wouldn't lose technical functions (except on the obvious differences) but yeh I'll ask as well. Thanks

Comment: Check out the info on the new transition to Lightning Editions happening this month. Existing Orgs (including yours) will be getting Sales Cloud licenses if they already have Service Cloud Licenses and vice versa. Your org will be affected by this. All editions will be getting the console and licenses for it.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link?  I am currently reading the summer 16' release notes but I can't seem to find it.  The Spring 16' discussed it but stated the Service Cloud isn't quite ready yet...

Comment: This is a May release that's happening beginning NOW. There was a webinar on it yesterday from Release Readiness. Here's a link to the [Deck](https://success.salesforce.com/0693A000005q8Y2) in the Success Community from the presentation.